# How does the chartjs line look start to be greater than 0

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

Image Chart:

[image]

I am in need of drawing 1 graph but when pouring data out it must start from other 0.0 its lines must start at 01-03. Is there a way out with the chartjs library

**how do i get my graph to start from nonzero, i.e. its line from 3-01 rather than from 0.0
here is my code**

```
const options = {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function (t, d) {
        let xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
        let yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$&,') : t.yLabel;
        return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
      }
    }
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        callback: function (value) {
          if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
            return value.toString().replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$&,');
          } else {
            return value;
          }
        },
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

**chart section displayed**

```
const labels = {!! json_encode($label) !!};
const dataPrice = {!! json_encode($data)!!};
new window.Chart(chart1, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: Object.values(labels),
    datasets: [{
      data: Object.values(dataPrice),
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      label: '{{  $dataset}}'
    }]
  },
  options: options
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an empty label and to the start of the labels array and a `null` value to the start of your dataArray to shift it a bit

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [null, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way like this?

[image]

I wish it would look from that number, not from 0.